# i'm having a lit of problem with my javascript game

Tags: javascript

i copied this little javascript game from github i started editing i made some new levels and whole new graphic design for the game. basiclly i did it for fun made new keybinds for the keyboard since it's playable for keyboard only.
then i had this idea to create a button that acts like a keyboard or directly make the character move
i tried  but it don't work
so here is my "controller.js"  which is responsible for the character movements 
with"htmlfile.html"

```js
const Controller = function() {
 
 
 

  this.left  = new Controller.ButtonInput();
  document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick =  this.right = new Controller.ButtonInput();;
  this.up    = new Controller.ButtonInput();
  

  

  this.keyDownUp = function(type, keycode) {

    var down = (type == "keydown") ? true : false;
      
   
   
   //old//
    switch(keycode) {

      case 37: this.left.getInput(down);  break;
     case 38: this.up.getInput(down);    break;
      case 39: this.right.getInput(down); break;
  // case 81: this.left.getInput(down);  break;
     // case 90: this.up.getInput(down);    break;
    //  case 68: this.right.getInput(down);
   //new//
  

    }

  };

};
//new//
//1- document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = doFunction;
//2-document.getElementById("demo").onclick =

        this.keyDownUp = function(type, button) {
   
   var down = (type == "keydown") ? true : false;
   
        $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
   
   
   
   switch(button) {

     case '1': this.left.getInput(down);  break; //notice BREAK
     case '2': this.right.getInput(down); break;
  case '3': this.up.getInput(down);    break;
    }
    }); 



}








Controller.prototype = {

  constructor : Controller

};

Controller.ButtonInput = function() {

  this.active = this.down = false;

};

Controller.ButtonInput.prototype = {

  constructor : Controller.ButtonInput,

  getInput : function(down) {

    if (this.down != down) this.active = down;
    this.down = down;

  }

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Added this meta tag 04/07/2018 -->
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
 
 
    <link href = "rabbit-trap.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">

 
 <!--input type="text" id="demo-->
 
 

    <title>Rabbit Trap</title>
 

  </head>

  <body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!center>
  

    <!-- Added a menu to navigate projects from the main page -->
    <div id = "menu">
      <p>menu</p>
      <div id = "menu-list">
        <br>
        <a href = "rabbit-trap.html?01">part1</a>
        <a href = "rabbit-trap.html?02">part2</a>
        <a href = "rabbit-trap.html?03">part3</a>
        <a href = "rabbit-trap.html?04">part4</a>
        <a href = "rabbit-trap.html?05">part5</a>
        <a href = "rabbit-trap.html?06">part6</a>
        <a href = "rabbit-trap.html?07">part7</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <canvas></canvas>

    <!-- Since Rabbit Trap is a multi-part series and I didn't feel like writing
    html and css for every single part, I decided to dynamically add the appropriate
    js file containing the game logic for each part based on url parameters. -->
    <script type = "text/javascript">

      let part = String(window.location).split("?")[1];

      /* Added on 03/09/2018 to allow reusing scripts from previous parts. */
      let parts = {

        "01":["01/controller-01.js", "01/display-01.js", "01/engine-01.js", "01/game-01.js", "01/main-01.js"],
        "02":["02/controller-02.js", "02/display-02.js", "01/engine-01.js", "02/game-02.js", "02/main-02.js"],
        "03":["02/controller-02.js", "03/display-03.js", "01/engine-01.js", "03/game-03.js", "03/main-03.js"],
        "04":["02/controller-02.js", "04/display-04.js", "01/engine-01.js", "04/game-04.js", "03/main-03.js"],
        "05":["02/controller-02.js", "05/display-05.js", "01/engine-01.js", "05/game-05.js", "05/main-05.js"],
        "06":["02/controller-02.js", "05/display-05.js", "06/engine-06.js", "06/game-06.js", "06/main-06.js"],
        "07":["02/controller-02.js", "05/display-05.js", "06/engine-06.js", "07/game-07.js", "07/main-07.js"],

      };

      switch(part) {

        case "01": case "02": case "03": case "04": case "05": case "06": case "07": break;
        default:
          part = "05";

      }
                //new//
    //<input type="button" value="button" id="movebutton" /> <!--removed inline JS-->
    
    //new//
      for (let index = 0; index < parts[part].length; index ++) {

        let script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src", parts[part][index]);
        document.head.appendChild(script);

      }

      let menu      = document.getElementById("menu");
      let menu_list = document.getElementById("menu-list");

      menu.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

        menu_list.style.display = (menu_list.style.display == "none") ? "grid" : "none";

      });

      menu_list.style.display = "none";

    </script>
 <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="right" />
 
 
 <input type="button" value="Change" id="1">
 <input type="button" value="Change" id="2">
 <input type="button" value="Change" id="3">
 
    
   
 
 
 <!/center>
 <!--new-->
<input type="button" value="button"  id="demon" /?> <!--removed inline JS-->
<button id="demo" onclick="right">right</button>


  </body>

</html>
```

sorry i know it's soo dirty code but i will try to clear the junk my self 
all i need is help to create a button for movements "left,right,up" 
thank you if you make it to the end and i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on moving a square using both keyboard and mouse(button elements)

```js
var pos = [0, 0], box = document.querySelector("#box"),
  directions = {"37": "Left", "38": "Up", "39": "Right", "40": "Down"};
document.querySelector("#controls").onclick = 
  document.querySelector("body").onkeyup = function(e) {
    var direction = e.type === "click" && e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON" ?
      e.target.textContent : directions[e.keyCode];
    
    switch(direction) {
      case "Right": {
        box.style.left = `${pos[0] + 50 > 300 ? 300 : pos[0] += 50}px`;
        break;
      }
      case "Left": {
        box.style.left = `${pos[0] - 50 < 0 ? 0 : pos[0] -= 50}px`;
        break;
      }
      case "Down": {
        box.style.top = `${pos[1] + 50 > 300 ? 300 : pos[1] += 50}px`;
        break;
      }
      case "Up": {
        box.style.top = `${pos[1] - 50 < 0 ? 0 : pos[1] -= 50}px`;
        break;
      }
    }
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333, -7px -2px 1px #ccc;
}
#controls button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: bold 24px monospace;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black, -0 -0 1px black;
}
#controls .solo {
  width: 100%;
}
#controls button:hover {
  outline: none;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="controls">
  <button class="solo">Up</button>
  <button>Left</button><button>Right</button>
  <button class="solo">Down</button>
</div>
```